# For which real $a$ does$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+a} \right\}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation, exponential-function

For which real $a$ does
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+a} \right\}$ 
converge or diverge?

This is a generalization of
[$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \right\}$. is this converge or diverge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964082/sum-n-1-infty-left-e-1-frac1nn-right-is-this-converge-or)
where it is shown that
the sum diverges for
$a=0$.

My conjecture is that
the sum converges for
$a = \frac12$
and diverges for
$a \ne \frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct.

Note that

$$\begin{align}\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n +a} &= \frac{n+a}{n+1/2}(n + 1/2)\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)\\&=\frac{n+a}{n+1/2}(n + 1/2)\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^2} +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3} \right) \right)  \\ &= \frac{n+a}{n+1/2}\left(1 + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right) \right) \\ &= \left(1 + \frac{a - 1/2}{n + 1/2} \right)\left(1 + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right) \right)\end{align}$$

We have convergence if $a = 1/2$ and divergence otherwise, since

$$e- \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n +a}= e - \exp \left(1 + \frac{a - 1/2}{n + 1/2} +  \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) \\ = e\frac{ 1/2-a}{n + 1/2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is correct, since
$$(n+\tau)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) = 1+\frac{\tau-\frac{1}{2}}{n}+\frac{\frac{\tau}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+o(1)}{n^2} $$
implies, by exponentiation,
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\tau}=e\left[1+\frac{\tau-\frac{1}{2}}{n}+\frac{\frac{11}{24}-\tau+\frac{\tau^2}{2}+o(1)}{n^2}\right].$$
Roughly $\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\right]\approx -\frac{2}{9}$.