# Is there a closed form for $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big(e-(1+1/n)^{n+1/2}\big)$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, eulers-number-e

Is there a closed form for
$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(e-\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}\right)$?

I think the 1/2 makes the sum converge.

The original question does not have the 1/2 and the resulting sum diverges.

Comment: Well, my first numerical test shows convergence.

Comment: You *think* it converges, but 2 years ago, you *knew* it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964111/for-which-real-a-does-sum-n-1-infty-left-e-left1-frac1n-right?rq=1

Comment: Then, Jack D'Aurizio calculated that the sum is approximately $-\frac29$, and while that's fairly accurate, a more precise value would be $-0.22288871647776126$. I don't think there is a closed expression.

Comment: This question was entered on my phone, which makes things much more difficult. 
Or else I am deteriorating.

Comment: [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)'s `sumnum` fails, but `sumnummonien(n=1,exp(1)-exp((n+1/2)*log(1+1/n)))` yields $$-0.22288871647776085027964664433341422592082466039487638241988238\ldots$$